# Display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: flexbox

I needed a way to get our website's product search results (divs) to all be given the same height as the other divs in the row. Since our product results have different title lengths, I cannot set a static height for each div, so I decided to use display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap on the parent div of our search result divs (#result-info-detail).

This method works great on Chrome and Firefox but unfortunately does not work well on Internet Explorer, and effectively renders poorly and prevents the page from being mobile responsive. I'm using IE11. Looking for a solution to this issue. Thanks!

Our search page: http://www.theexecutiveadvertising.com/Results.aspx?keyword=pen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 0):

I used a third party CSS Browser Selector to specifically target IE users only: http://ridjohansen.github.io/css_browser_selector/index_en.html

I gave my product results static heights at various browser widths (using media queries) and used display: inline-block instead of display: flex, because it is not supported in IE.